Next auth refresh token rotation: the refresh token gets expired when changing tabs in a NextAuth.js application
Next auth refresh token rotation:the refresh token gets expired when changing tabs in a NextAuth.js application.This is[...nextauth] auth - options.ts  Any idea about the issue?
**What could be the potential issue?
The token expiration time might not be correctly calculated or stored, causing the token to appear expired when switching tabs ?
Tokens might not be properly synchronized across tabs, leading to inconsistent token states?
**
refreshAccessToken method
   export async function refreshAccessToken(token) {
    try {
        const url = "url"

        const response = await fetch(url, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: "Bearer accessToken",
                Accept: 'application/json',
            },
            method: 'POST',
        })

        const refreshedTokens = await response.json()

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw refreshedTokens
        }

        return {...token,
            accessToken: refreshedTokens.access_token,
            accessTokenExpires: refreshedTokens.expires_in,
        }
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error) return {...token,
            error: 'RefreshAccessTokenError',
        }
    }}

customProvider method
const customProvider: OAuthConfig < any > ={
        id: 'customProvider',
        name: 'customProvider',
        type: 'oauth',
        authorization: {
            url: "/oauth/authorize",
            params: {
                app_id: appId,
                code_challenge_method: CODE_CHALLENGE_METHOD,
            },
        },
        clientId: appId,
        token: {
            async request({
                params
            }) {
                const {
                    code_verifier_value
                } = useCookies() try {
                    const response = await exchangeCode({
                        code: params.code,
                        code_verifier: code_verifier_value,
                    })
    
                    if (!response.access_token) {
                        throw new Error('Access token not found in the response')
                    }
                    return {
                        tokens: response
                    }
                } catch(error) {
                    throw new Error(`Token request failed: $ {
                        error
                    }`)
                }
            },
        },
        userinfo: "/auth/user",
        profile: (profile: any) = >{
            return {...profile.data,
                id: profile.data.email,
            }
        },}

authOptions here
export const authOptions = {
            providers: [customProvider],
            secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
            pages: {
                signIn: '/login',
            },
            callbacks: {
                async jwt({
                    token,
                    account,
                    user
                }) {
                    if (user) {
                        if (account) {
                            return {...token,
                                accessToken: user.token.access_token,
                                data: user.data,
                                accessTokenExpires: account.expires_at,
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (account) {
                            return {...token,
                                accessToken: account.access_token,
                                accessTokenExpires: account.expires_at,
                            }
                        }
                    }
        
                    // If accessTokenExpiry is 5 mins, we have to refresh token before 5 mins pass. So this would be the refreshThreshold
                    const shouldRefreshTime = Math.round(token.accessTokenExpires - 5 * 60 - Date.now(), )
        
                    if (shouldRefreshTime > 0) {
                        return token
                    }
        
                    return refreshAccessToken(token)
                },
                async session({
                    session,
                    token
                }) {
        
                    const {
                        accessToken,
                        data
                    } = token
        
                    session.accessToken = accessToken
        
                    session.user = user
        
                    return session
                },
                async redirect({
                    url,
                    baseUrl
                }) {
                    return url
                },
            },
            events: {
                signOut: async({
                    token
                }) = >{
                    const {
                        accessToken
                    } = token
                    try {
                        await logout(accessToken)
                    } catch(error) {
                        console.log('error from auth', error)
                    }
                },
            },}

export const getServerSession = async() = >await serverSession(authOptions)


A problem arises when the user opens multiple tabs, and they all trigger to refresh the tokens at the same time. Each tab gets new tokens that are different from each other
